# Assembly: Error when attempting to increment at array index

Tags: arrays, assembly, x86, tasm

Here's a small snippet of assembly code (TASM) where I simply try to increment the value at the current index of the array. The idea is that the "freq" array will store a number (DWord size) that represents how many times that ASCII character was seen in the file. To keep the code short, "b" stores the current byte being read.

```
Declared in data segment
freq DD 256 DUP (0)
b    DB ?
___________
Assume b contains current byte
mov bl, b
sub bh, bh
add bx, bx
inc freq[bx]
```

I receive this error at compilation time at the line containing "inc freq[bx]": ***ERROR*** Argument to operation or instruction has illegal size.

Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

There is no `inc` that can increment a dword in 16 bit mode. You will have to synthesize it from add/adc, such as:

```
add freq[bx], 1
adc freq[bx + 2], 0
```

You might need to add a size override, such as `word ptr` or change your array definition to `freq DW 512 DUP (0)`.

Also note that you have to scale the index by 4, not 2.

Comment: Changing the array definition to `freq DW 512 DUP (0)` did the trick. Thank you very much for your help.